# Jordan Canonical Form - Set of Linearly Independent Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

It is part of Jordan Canonical form where we form a set of vectors, and they are linearly independent. 
I have attempted by putting the vectors into a linear combination that equals zero. For it to be linearly independent, all the coefficients will need to be zero. 
But we know that the vector is in kth eigenspace but not in k-1 th eigenspace. 
So (A-lambda*I)^k v = 0 vector but not with k-1. 
I'm quite stuck from how to approach from there.

Please help

Thank you

Comment: I've taken the liberty of embedding the image, but it would be better if you typeset it using MathJax.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that there is some linear relationship $\Sigma_{i = 0}^{k-1} a_i (A - \lambda I)^i v$. Think of this relationship as a tuple $a = (a_{k-1}, a_{k-2}, \ldots, a_0)$.

Multiplying by $(A - \lambda I)$ has the affect of shifting the tuple $a$ one step to the left, and leaves you with a linear relationship still. Now we know also that $(a_{k-2}, a_{k-3}, \ldots, a_0,0)$ is a linear relationship between these vectors. You can keep applying this idea to get that $(a_0, \ldots, 0,0)$ is a linear relationship, so that $a_0 = 0$ (here we use that $(A - \lambda I)^{k-1} v \not = 0$   !).

Continuing in this way, you get that all of the coefficients $a_i$ must have been zero.

Comment: It was hard to understand at first, but trying one by one in order made sense! Thank you so much!

Comment: @CathyKim You are welcome. Be sure to write out all of the details to make sure this really works, because I didn't! (But I am pretty sure it works.)